# The socket.io connection returns an empty array. Ways to receive data in React without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I create a chrome extension in React. I am trying to download data via socket.io. I didn't get any errors, but the array is empty.

**I should set the header and token, but I do not know where to do it in the `app.js` server. Where can I set:**

```
const token = '12345'

headers: {
  'Authorization': `Bearer $ {token}`
}
```

**How can I set `port` in server `app.js` and endpoint in client `app.jsx` if I create `chrome extension`?**

Is there any other way (other than socket.io) to receive data in the method `componentDidMount()` in `React` without reloading the page?

When I go to the address `http://127.0.0.1:4001`, the console.log displays to me `New client connected` and `Error: undefined`

**Server**

//app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const axios = require("axios");
const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;/How port in `chrome extension?`
const index = require("./routes/index");
const app = express();
app.use(index);
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server); // < Interesting!
const token = "12345"; 


let interval;
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 10000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
});

const getApiAndEmit = async socket => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://b.application.com/api/v1/scores?expand=createdBy"
      ); // Getting the data from DarkSky
      socket.emit("FromAPI", res.data); // Emitting a new message. It will be consumed by the client
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
    }
  };

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

//index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ response: "I am alive" }).status(200);
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Client**

//app.jsx

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scores: []
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001" /How endpoint in `chrome extension`?
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
  const { endpoint } = this.state;
  const token = "12345"; 

  const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);

  socket.on("FromAPI", data => this.setState({ todos: data }));
}


  render () {
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If it's a content script, Chrome no longer allows cross-origin requests there, see section 2 in the [official CORB explainer](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).

Comment: In the react app you're creating a socket connection to `https://b.application.com/api/v1/scores?expand=createdBy`, shouldn't you be connecting to your own server app because your server app seems to make a request to this URL and send the response through the websocket.

Comment: @Titus So I have to change my endpoint in app.jsx client?

Comment: Can you explain the flow more? You want your chrome extension to connect to your socket io server and your server fetches data from endpoint and returns? Or you want your extension to directly pull data from endpoint?

Comment: @MunimMunna I retrieve the data in `componentDidMount (), axios.get, url: https: //b.application.com/api/v1/scores? Expand = createdBy`. I want to fetch data without reloading the page. I do not want to refresh the page every time.

Comment: @MunimMunna I want to pull data from url: `https://b.application.com/api/v1/scores?expand=createdBy`.  Do you know any other ways except socket.io?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it:

```
const getApiAndEmit = async socket => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://b.application.com/api/v1/scores?expand=createdBy",
         headers: {
           Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
         }
      ); 
      socket.emit("FromAPI", res.data); // Emitting a new message. It will be consumed by the client
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-----------Try Replacing app.js:- -----------------

const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const axios = require("axios");
const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;/How port in `chrome extension?`
const index = require("./routes/index");
const app = express();
app.use(index);
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server); // < Interesting!
const token = "12345"; 
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
let interval;
io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 10000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
});

const getApiAndEmit = async socket => {
    try {
        const res = await axios("https://b.application.com/api/v1/scores?expand=createdBy", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                'token': token
            }
        }); // Getting the data from DarkSky
        console.log("res.data:- "+JSON.stringify(res.data,null,4));
        socket.emit("FromAPI", res.data);  // Emitting a new message. It wil be consumed by the client
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
    }
};

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: In console I see only `New client connected` and
`Error: undefined`

Comment: "https://b.application.com/api/v1/scores?expand=createdBy" you are trying to fetch data from correct api right?????

Comment: Yes. I fetch early dates in componentDidMount(), axios.get and was ok

Comment: replace error line with console.error("error:- ",error);
and let me know what it prints

Comment: `data: { error: 'Your request was made with invalid credentials.' } },
  isAxiosError: true`.       Token is valid, because I use it in componentDidMount() and I normal fetch data

Comment: Do you know how to use postman?
If yes then first try to get output using postman and then do the actual implementation.

Comment: In postman I choosen method 'get' and 'headers' I set  Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin and token. I have error  `"error": "Your request was made with invalid credentials."
}`

Comment: When I choosen in Postman method 'get', authorization 'Bearer token' I can recieve dates. Token is valid.

Comment: I solved it. The items you added are not needed: `app.use`, `Content-Type`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Instead of `token` you should add `Authorization: Bearer $ {token}`. I edited your post and correct it. Vote up for your intentions.

Comment: Thanks and well done...
Finally, our motto was the correct solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196108/discussion-between-umbro-and-piyush).

Answer (score 0):

### Try modifying app.jsx as:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            scores: [],
            receivedData:[],
            endpoint: "https://b.application.com/api/v1/scores?expand=createdBy",
            token: "12345"
        }
        this.onDataReceived = this.onDataReceived.bind(this);
        this.socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint, {
            extraHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.token}`
            }
        });
        this.socket.on("FromAPI", this.onDataReceived);
    }
    onDataReceived(receivedData) {
        console.log("receivedData ", receivedData);
        this.setState({
            receivedData: receivedData
        });
    }
        render() {
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
    }
}
export default App;
```

---

### Try modifying app.js: function getApiAndEmit

replace the line: socket.emit("FromAPI", res.data);

io.emit("FromAPI", res.data);

Comment: what is the value of receivedData?
can you please elaborate?

Comment: it's empty array

Comment: Where can I put token in app.js server?